# Dynamic definition of active tab

Tags: javascript, class, binding, tabs, bootstrap-4

I have 3 tabs. In some cases the first one is hidden.
The first one is the active one. If it's hidden, the 2nd one should be active.

**.html code:**

```
    <div class="Settings">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs p">
        <li class="nav-item active i-tab">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#bla" data-bind="text: strings.iTabHeader, visible: isVis"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item f-tab">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#blabla" data-bind="text: strings.fTabHeader"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item b-tab">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#blablabla" data-bind="text: strings.bTabHeader"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="iSettingMenu" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <div data-bind="compose: iSettings"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="fSettingsMenu" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <div data-bind="compose: fSettings"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="bSettingsMenu" class="tab-pane fade">
            <div data-bind="compose: bSettings"></div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**.js Code:**

```
this.isvis = ko.computed(function () {
            return this.Type() === 'xxxx';
        }.bind(this));
```

Comment: What does "hidden" mean? ``display: none`` or ``visibility: hidden``. Or something else?

Comment: Thanks @Kokogino. "visible: isVis" - Its visibility is defined according to binding.

Comment: But how do you hide it? In the CSS or do you delete it entirely in javascript?

Comment: @Kokogino (js was added). Maybe I'm missing something because I've just started to develop for web, but the visible property is binded to a function in the JS file. Am I clear? :/